# How to reduce the length of the paragraph by dots(...)?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a p tag,

```
<p> best villan in the film industry</p>
```

i have to cut the sentence after 8 characters, but after that dots should appear.
like

```
 best vil...
```

How to make it using css?
If its possible by angular js also appreciated

Comment: You might use angular-truncate https://github.com/igreulich/angular-truncate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use text-overflow: ellipsis; property. Write like this

```
#content_right_head span{
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Y5vpb/

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can also create a filter and pass it the number of characters you want to keep.
here is an implementation example: https://github.com/sparkalow/angular-truncate

another example: jsfiddle.net/tuyyx/

Answer (score 0):

Using angularjs

Define scope variable in controller

```
$scope.ParaValue= "best villan in the film industry"
```

Use scope variable in View

```
<p>
{{ ParaValue.length > 8 ? ParaValue.substring(0,8)+'.....' :ParaValue}}
</p>
```

Comment: it might not b a good solution, for example if <p> is inside some ng-repeat.