# displays the first 4 words of a phrase in html

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I have a long phrase and I want to show the first 4 words.

**example:**

```
The style of this paper is a combination of an external stylesheet, and internal style.
```

become like this:

**The style of this ...**

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442069/how-to-reduce-the-length-of-the-paragraph-by-dots

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956610/how-to-select-first-10-words-of-a-sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for that. It takes the first four words and adds some dots,

```js
var text = 'The style of this paper is a combination of an external stylesheet, and internal style.';
document.write(text.replace(/^((\w*\W*){0,4}).*/, '$1...'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which returns the first N words from the text of an element. For example:

```
function firstWords(wrapperId, wordCount) {
    var element = document.getElementById(wrapperId);
    var textArray = element.textContent.split(/\s/);
    if(textArray.length >= wordCount) {
        return textArray.slice(0, wordCount).join(" ");
    } else {
        return textArray.join(" ");
    }
}
```

Afterwards if the wrapper has ID "foo" for example as

```
<div id="foo">This is a sample text!</div>
```

you can call

```
console.log(firstWords("foo", 4));
```

Answer (score -2):

use

```
strArr[] = str.split(" ");
```

`str[0]` , `str[1]`, `str[2]`, `str[3]` is the resultant what you want to use.